# how to copy a map <string, int> into a vector <int, string>

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, copy, std

my code copies the map in the same order

map <string, int> to vector <string, int>

I want this instead

map <string, int> to vector <int, string>

is it possible with std copy?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  
  fstream fs; 
  fs.open("test_text.txt"); 
  if(!fs.is_open()){
    cout << "could not open file" << endl; 
  }

  map <string, int> mp; 
  string word; 
  while(fs >> word){

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
      if(ispunct(word[i])){
        word.erase(i--, 1);
      }
    }

    if(mp.find(word) != mp.end()){
      mp[word]++; 
    }
  }

  vector <pair <string, int> > v(mp.size()); 
  copy(mp.begin(), mp.end(), v.begin()); 
 
  


  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `map<string, int>` might contain negative ints. Where would you put those in the `vector`? If - by the code - it won't, then it's suggested to use `size_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: @lorro I don't understand your question

Comment: @brah79 `for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){ if(ispunct(word[i])){ word.erase(i--, 1); }` --> That entire loop could have been `word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), ispunct), word.end());`  Not only safer, but faster.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie looks a lot better thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of different ways, but this will work

```
vector<pair<int, string>> v;
v.reserve(mp.size());
for (const auto& p : mp)
    v.emplace_back(p.second, p.first);
```

Does't seem to be possible with `std::copy` since your value types are different and the source is not convertible to the destination. It should be possible with `std::transform`.